# How to find the $\arctan(2\sqrt{3})$ by hand?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the polar form of the complex number $zw$ where $z = 1 + i$. and $w = \sqrt{3} + i$.

I multiplied foiled the complex numbers, grouped the real and imaginary terms together to get a modulus of $\sqrt{8}$ and an angle of $\theta = \arctan(2\sqrt{3})$. I dont know how to find this, i do know that $\arctan(\sqrt{3})$ is $\pi/3$ but i dont know how to incorporate the multiplied 2. The answer is given as $5\pi/12$.

Comment: LaTeX tip: use $\{\text{braces}\}$ instead of $(\text{parentheses})$ as arguments to commands, i.e. `\sqrt{3}` instead of `\sqrt(3)`. (I fixed this in your post.)

Comment: $\arctan(2\sqrt 3)$ is not equal to $\pi/12$. Check it with your calculator.

Comment: sorry, I meant $5\pi /12$

Comment: Your end goal is to find the argument of $(1+i)(\sqrt{3}+i)$? Well, that number is $(\sqrt{3}-1)+i(1+\sqrt{3})$, which is in the first quadrant, so its argument is $\arctan \left ( \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1} \right )=\arctan \left ( 2 + \sqrt{3} \right )$.

Comment: $\arctan(2\sqrt 3)$ is not equal to $5\pi/12$ either.

Comment: it is nearly equivalent - this is why i think the answer below of using a taylor approximation may be accurate

Comment: OMG.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: oh i see that I found the incorrect argument for arctan. Thank you Ian

Comment: Referenced Taylor series diverge for argument greater than 1, which is the case here

Comment: In fact, $\arctan(2+\sqrt{3})=5\pi/12$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For the solution of the problem you do not need to evaluate this $\arctan$. Recall that the argument of the product is the sum of arguments of the factors and the latter are very easy to evaluate.

> $$\frac\pi4+\frac\pi6=\frac {5\pi}{12}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You should recognize that the argument of $z=1+i$ is $\frac\pi4.$
You should also recognize that the argument of $w = \sqrt3 + i$
is $\arctan(1/\sqrt3),$ which you should realize is $\frac\pi2 - \frac\pi3 = \frac\pi6.$

So $zw$ is the product of a number whose argument is $\frac\pi4$
and  a number whose argument is $\frac\pi6.$
The argument of $zw$ is therefore

$$\frac\pi4 + \frac\pi6.$$

I will let you finish from there!

In my opinion, any attempt to evaluate $\arctan(2+\sqrt3)$ in this context by any other method than the above is a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you very much!